# How to solve this tagging system routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a tag resource in routes.rb: `resources :tags` as well as a tag link code snippet: `get 'tags/:tag', to: 'users#index', as: :tag`.

The tag link code snippet allows me to click on a tag link and be routed to the user index page with a list of all users who have been tagged with that tag. The link is of the form `http://localhost:3000/tags/{tag_name}`

Unfortunately these two ideas are clashing because when I try to add a new tag via the tag resource, the link generated is `http://localhost:3000/tags/new`. Which leads to ambiguity because "new" can be either an action or a tag name.

I'm a rails beginner, any ideas on how to solve this? Most of the code I'm using is from the railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging?view=asciicast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
In your UsersController

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  @users = @users.where(tag: params[:tag]) if params[:tag]
end
```

Your url

```
http://localhost:3000/users?tag=your_tag
```

Your view

```
link_to 'Your tag', "#{users_path}?tag=your_tag"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try FriendlyId gem (https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) and use show action to redirect to users controller.